# Entity Framework criação de banco

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Sou novo com entity e estou seguindo um passo a passo para criar uma aplicação Code First **( http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx )**.

Criei a aplicação, debuguei e ela roda perfeitamente sem nenhum erro, porém nenhum banco é criado... Segue a Main do código e o App.config:

Creio que seja algum problema de configuração ou algo do tipo...Alguém mais experiente tem uma ideia do que pode ser?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
        {
            Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };

            try
            {
                ctx.Students.Add(stud);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
    EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="entityFramework" connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
      </startup>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
         <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu lido com Entity, eu crio as modes, defino a classe de contexto (com os DbSet), vou até e console do VS e faço o seguinte: 
(isso depois de instalar o entity)

Enable-migrations

Add-migration CriarBanco

Update-database -verbose

Nisso ele verifica a existência de banco e compara as tabelas com as models, editando o banco de acordo com alterações feitas na model. Não existindo banco, ele cria.

Não sei dizer se isso ajuda

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo. Fiz a configuração mas o banco ainda não é criado ao executar...